# stupid backoff language model

Tags: model, implementation

In section 4.1 (Normalized Stupid Backoff) of "One Billion Word Benchmark ..." by Chelba, Mikolov, et.al., it states:

... the Stupid Backoff model does not generate normalized probabilities. For the purpose of computing perplexity ... values output by the model were normalized over the entire LM vocabulary.

Assuming a bigram LM, the obvious way to interpret this is to score all single words (using MLE) and score pairs of words using the standard backoff formula, sum the unigram and bigram scores, yielding Sigma, then divide each (unigram or bigram) score by Sigma. Is this the correct interpretation of the quote?

Comment: Is this a question for Stack Overflow? I don't see any code and it doesn't seem like a question about code but a question about interpretation. I would reference another Stack Exchange site because I am sure there must be one, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: I agree with the comment by Sethmr. FWIW, I have used the approach described in the original question. It behave as it should: the calculated values for bigrams and unigrams are all in the open interval (0,1) and sum to 1.